# Reverse a string without strtok in C

Tags: c, split, char, reverse, c-strings

Working on a program that uses RPN (Reverse Polish Notation).

I have a function that reverses all the words of string without using `strtok` or triggering `printf` (unlike all the solutions found online and here).

The function actually works partially as it prints all the words of a given string except the last one and I need help figuring out what's going on.

```
char *extract(char s[]) {
    if (s[0] == '\0') 
        return NULL;
    int i = 0;
    char *p = NULL;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
            p = s + i;
        i++;
    }
    if (p != NULL) {
        *p = '\0';
        return p + 1;
    }
}
```

And then it's called in main like this:

```
char s[MAX] = "5 60 +";
while(s != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", extract(s));
}
```

The output is `+ 60` with the cursor endessly waiting for something
but the expected output should be `+ 60 5`

Comment: Why do you want to reverse the strings? Reverse Polish is designed to be parsed left to right, using a stack to store intermediate values.

Comment: And a [example] would be helpful to help you.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow examle added

Comment: @androidexpert35 Expert on android, your function does not make sense.:)

Comment: If you split the input string by storing `'\0'` between words, why do you expect to be able to use only *one* `printf()`? And what do you think will `printf()` print if given `NULL`?

Comment: Your `extract` function doesn't return anything when `p` is `NULL` (when no space character is found). I think it should return a pointer to the start of the string `s` in that case.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow java is always easier to manage hahah, most of the people do this program using a linked list, i think is a waste of memory and data for such a simple program

Comment: @androidexpert35 you didn't add a [MCVE]. Your example is minimal but not complete. BTW your las edit messed up the formatting.

Comment: This should be trivial to fix if you compiled with warnings and if you stepped through the code with a debugger.

Comment: This condition will never be false: `while(s!=NULL)`

Comment: Please don't cram your C syntax together (common noob thing) just because the flexibility tolerates it. The goal is always to make code clear and easy to read, understand visually parse, since 90% of the life of a program is in the maintenance. Look around the net, github, various open source projects. They have C styling requirements for any code that goes into the gate period. Every company I've worked for does too, so it's a good idea to get into good habits early. Clean carefully named and formatted code will save you vast debugging grief in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach is to reverse each word within a string and then to reverse the whole string.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char * reverse( char *s, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[ i ];
        s[ i ] = s[ n - i - 1 ];
        s[ n - i - 1 ] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

char * reverse_by_words( char *s )
{
    const char *delim = " \t";

    char *p = s;

    while ( *p )
    {
        p += strspn( p, delim );

        if ( *p )
        {
            char *q = p;

            p += strcspn( p, delim );

            reverse( q, p - q );
        }
    }

    return reverse( s, p - s );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "5 60 +";

    puts( s );

    puts( reverse_by_words( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 60 +
+ 60 5
```

If you want to keep leading and trailing spaces as they were in the original string then the functions can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *reverse( char *s, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i -1 ];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

char * reverse_by_words( char *s )
{
    const char *delim = " \t";

    char *first = s, *last = s;

    for ( char *p = s;  *p; )
    {
        p += strspn( p, delim );

        if ( last == s ) first = last = p;


        if ( *p )
        {
            char *q = p;

            p += strcspn( p, delim );

            last = p;

            reverse( q, p - q );
        }
    }

    reverse( first, last - first );

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "\t\t\t5 60 +";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", reverse_by_words( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"           5 60 +"
"           + 60 5"
```